# Issue for setting defaultHeader in controller

Tags: angularjs, rest

Whenever i set defaultHeader in my auth-cntrl for basic authentication, it works for the first time.But if i refresh the page my authentication API give
'No Authorization' error.

```
app.controller('authCtrl',['$scope','Restangular','userServices','$location','$base64','cookie', '$mdToast', '$animate', function ($scope,Restangular,userServices,$location,$base64,cookie,$mdToast,$animate){
$scope.signIn = function() {
    var data = {
            "Username": $scope.username,
            "Password": $scope.password
    };
    credBase64 = $base64.encode(unescape(encodeURIComponent($scope.username +':'+ $scope.password)));
Restangular.setDefaultHeaders({'Authorization': 'Basic ' + credBase64});
    userServices.users(Restangular).post(data).then(function(response){
        if(response.success) {
            cookie.set('session',credBase64);
            $location.path('/workplace');
        }else {
            $location.path('/signin');
        }
    });
};
}]);
```

Comment: javascript isn't persistent across page loads. You only set headers in signIn function... need logic for page load also

Comment: Can you please suggest some logic for handling page load.